# Physical storage of COBOL PACKED-DECIMAL field on Little Endian machines

Tags: cobol, packed-decimal

I understand the shape of the bytes behind a `PACKED-DECIMAL` number when on a Big-Endian machine. What I have not been able to discover is what shape would those bytes take on a Little-Endian machine.

**Note:** The reason I believe there does exist a separate format for such is because the IBM MQ Encoding field has the following values:-

- `MQENC_DECIMAL_NORMAL`
- `MQENC_DECIMAL_REVERSED`

Of `MQENC_DECIMAL_REVERSED` it simply says:-

> Packed-decimal integers are represented in the same way as `MQENC_DECIMAL_NORMAL`, but with the bytes arranged in reverse order. The bits within each byte are arranged in the same way as `MQENC_DECIMAL_NORMAL`.

Can anyone corroborate or refute this description?

For example, the number +123.45 stored in a `PIC 9(3)V99 COMP-3` would have the following bytes:-

```
12 34 5C
```

The above quote suggests to me that if in reversed, the same packed decimal number would be represented on a Little-Endian machine as:-

```
5C 34 12
```

**N.B.** I have not tagged this question with `ibm-mq`, as I don't really think the crux of my question has anything to do with IBM MQ. It is simply the reason I am asking.

Comment: It's not clear what you're really asking here. You don't need corroboration of what it says in the MQ specification, and what IBM Cobol does with a `COMP-3` data item has been fixed for at least 58 years. Please clarify.

Comment: While it's true that the bytes would be in the reverse order, COBOL compilers on little-endian machines may still be storing & processing data in big-endian format. At least one does that, presumably to assist with data compatibility across platforms. Compare, for example, MQENC-NATIVE in the copybooks with MQENC_NATIVE in the header files.So I don't know how much use the DECIMAL_REVERSED actually gets.

Comment: HI @user207421 - I am not asking what IBM COBOL on z/OS does. That is clear to me, as I say at the start of my question. I am asking what Little-Endian machines do. i.e. those not on z/OS. The answer seems to suggest that they do not reverse the bytes. This was the refutation of the description I was looking for.

Comment: @MarkTaylor - this was my fear. MQ messages containing packed decimal data which is then moved to a Little-Endian machine. What data conversion should it undergo for example? The default encoding for Windows and Linux is x222, which includes DECIMAL_REVERSED, but it would seem that either this is a lie, or the definition of DECIMAL_REVERSED is the same as DECIMAL_NORMAL.

Comment: @user207421 I am looking for either corroboration or refutation of the statement that packed decimal has its bytes in reversed order on Little-Endian platforms and I have accepted the answer below that provides refutation. Why do you feel I require luck? Are you saying it is hard to prove 100%? I would certainly agree with that, but I'm hoping for at least a general feeling from the myriad of experts using COBOL on Little-Endian platforms that read this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like packed data is stored in "normal" byte order.

The following program was compiled with OpenCOBOL 1.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad...

```
   ID Division.
   Program-ID. testcmp3.
   Environment Division.
   Input-Output Section.
   File-Control.
       Select OUTPUT01 Assign To './output01'
           Status OUTPUT01-STATUS.
   Data Division.
   File Section.
   FD  OUTPUT01
       Record 16
       Block 0
       Recording F.
   01  OUTPUT01-REC PIC X(016).

   Working-Storage Section.
   01  CONSTANTS.
       05  MYNAME             PIC X(008) VALUE 'testcmp3'.

   01  WS-OUTPUT01-REC.
       05  WS-OUT-S94COMP     PIC S9(004) COMP   VALUE +0.
       05  FILLER             PIC X(001)         VALUE HIGH-VALUES.
       05  WS-OUT-S95COMP3    PIC S9(005) COMP-3 VALUE +0.
       05  FILLER             PIC X(008)         VALUE SPACES.

   01  WORK-AREAS.
       05  OUTPUT01-STATUS    PIC X(002)         VALUE ZEROES.

   Procedure Division.
   OPEN OUTPUT OUTPUT01
   IF OUTPUT01-STATUS NOT = '00'
       DISPLAY 
         MYNAME 
         ' open of OUTPUT01 status = ' 
         OUTPUT01-STATUS
   END-IF

   PERFORM 100-WRITE 100 TIMES

   CLOSE OUTPUT01
   STOP RUN.

   100-WRITE.
       WRITE OUTPUT01-REC FROM WS-OUTPUT01-REC
       ADD 1 TO WS-OUT-S94COMP
       ADD 1 TO WS-OUT-S95COMP3
       .
```

...with the option `binary-byteorder` set to `native`.

The resulting file, displayed with the `hexdump` program, follows.

```
00000000  00 00 ff 00 00 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
00000010  01 00 ff 00 00 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
00000020  02 00 ff 00 00 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....,          |
00000030  03 00 ff 00 00 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....<          |
00000040  04 00 ff 00 00 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....L          |
00000050  05 00 ff 00 00 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....\          |
00000060  06 00 ff 00 00 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....l          |
00000070  07 00 ff 00 00 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....|          |
00000080  08 00 ff 00 00 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
00000090  09 00 ff 00 00 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
000000a0  0a 00 ff 00 01 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
000000b0  0b 00 ff 00 01 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
000000c0  0c 00 ff 00 01 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....,          |
000000d0  0d 00 ff 00 01 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....<          |
000000e0  0e 00 ff 00 01 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....L          |
000000f0  0f 00 ff 00 01 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....\          |
00000100  10 00 ff 00 01 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....l          |
00000110  11 00 ff 00 01 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....|          |
00000120  12 00 ff 00 01 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
00000130  13 00 ff 00 01 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
00000140  14 00 ff 00 02 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
00000150  15 00 ff 00 02 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
00000160  16 00 ff 00 02 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....,          |
00000170  17 00 ff 00 02 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....<          |
00000180  18 00 ff 00 02 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....L          |
00000190  19 00 ff 00 02 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....\          |
000001a0  1a 00 ff 00 02 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....l          |
000001b0  1b 00 ff 00 02 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....|          |
000001c0  1c 00 ff 00 02 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
000001d0  1d 00 ff 00 02 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
000001e0  1e 00 ff 00 03 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
000001f0  1f 00 ff 00 03 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |......          |
00000200  20 00 ff 00 03 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  | ....,          |
00000210  21 00 ff 00 03 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |!....<          |
00000220  22 00 ff 00 03 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |"....L          |
00000230  23 00 ff 00 03 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |#....\          |
00000240  24 00 ff 00 03 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |$....l          |
00000250  25 00 ff 00 03 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |%....|          |
00000260  26 00 ff 00 03 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |&.....          |
00000270  27 00 ff 00 03 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |'.....          |
00000280  28 00 ff 00 04 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |(.....          |
00000290  29 00 ff 00 04 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |).....          |
000002a0  2a 00 ff 00 04 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |*....,          |
000002b0  2b 00 ff 00 04 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |+....<          |
000002c0  2c 00 ff 00 04 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |,....L          |
000002d0  2d 00 ff 00 04 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |-....\          |
000002e0  2e 00 ff 00 04 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.....l          |
000002f0  2f 00 ff 00 04 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |/....|          |
00000300  30 00 ff 00 04 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |0.....          |
00000310  31 00 ff 00 04 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |1.....          |
00000320  32 00 ff 00 05 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |2.....          |
00000330  33 00 ff 00 05 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |3.....          |
00000340  34 00 ff 00 05 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |4....,          |
00000350  35 00 ff 00 05 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |5....<          |
00000360  36 00 ff 00 05 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |6....L          |
00000370  37 00 ff 00 05 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |7....\          |
00000380  38 00 ff 00 05 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |8....l          |
00000390  39 00 ff 00 05 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |9....|          |
000003a0  3a 00 ff 00 05 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |:.....          |
000003b0  3b 00 ff 00 05 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |;.....          |
000003c0  3c 00 ff 00 06 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |<.....          |
000003d0  3d 00 ff 00 06 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |=.....          |
000003e0  3e 00 ff 00 06 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |>....,          |
000003f0  3f 00 ff 00 06 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |?....<          |
00000400  40 00 ff 00 06 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |@....L          |
00000410  41 00 ff 00 06 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |A....\          |
00000420  42 00 ff 00 06 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |B....l          |
00000430  43 00 ff 00 06 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |C....|          |
00000440  44 00 ff 00 06 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |D.....          |
00000450  45 00 ff 00 06 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |E.....          |
00000460  46 00 ff 00 07 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |F.....          |
00000470  47 00 ff 00 07 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |G.....          |
00000480  48 00 ff 00 07 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |H....,          |
00000490  49 00 ff 00 07 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |I....<          |
000004a0  4a 00 ff 00 07 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |J....L          |
000004b0  4b 00 ff 00 07 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |K....\          |
000004c0  4c 00 ff 00 07 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |L....l          |
000004d0  4d 00 ff 00 07 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |M....|          |
000004e0  4e 00 ff 00 07 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |N.....          |
000004f0  4f 00 ff 00 07 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |O.....          |
00000500  50 00 ff 00 08 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |P.....          |
00000510  51 00 ff 00 08 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |Q.....          |
00000520  52 00 ff 00 08 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |R....,          |
00000530  53 00 ff 00 08 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |S....<          |
00000540  54 00 ff 00 08 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |T....L          |
00000550  55 00 ff 00 08 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |U....\          |
00000560  56 00 ff 00 08 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |V....l          |
00000570  57 00 ff 00 08 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |W....|          |
00000580  58 00 ff 00 08 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |X.....          |
00000590  59 00 ff 00 08 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |Y.....          |
000005a0  5a 00 ff 00 09 0c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |Z.....          |
000005b0  5b 00 ff 00 09 1c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |[.....          |
000005c0  5c 00 ff 00 09 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |\....,          |
000005d0  5d 00 ff 00 09 3c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |]....<          |
000005e0  5e 00 ff 00 09 4c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |^....L          |
000005f0  5f 00 ff 00 09 5c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |_....\          |
00000600  60 00 ff 00 09 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |`....l          |
00000610  61 00 ff 00 09 7c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |a....|          |
00000620  62 00 ff 00 09 8c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |b.....          |
00000630  63 00 ff 00 09 9c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |c.....          |
00000640
```

The draft standard document ISO/IEC CD2.1 1989:202x says of the USAGE PACKED-DECIMAL phrase...

> The USAGE PACKED-DECIMAL clause specifies that a radix of 10 is used
> to represent a numeric item in the storage of the computer.
> Furthermore, this clause specifies that each digit position shall
> occupy the minimum possible configuration in computer storage. Each
> implementor specifies the precise effect of the USAGE PACKED-DECIMAL
> clause upon the alignment and representation of the data item in the
> storage of the computer, including the representation of any algebraic
> sign. Sufficient computer storage shall be allocated by the
> implementor to contain the maximum range of values implied by the
> associated decimal picture character-string. If the WITH NO SIGN
> phrase is specified the representation of the data item in the storage
> of the computer reserves no storage for representing any sign value.
> The PICTURE character string of the data item shall not contain the
> symbol ‘S’; the data item is always considered to have a zero, or
> positive value.

Comment: I have only seen packed-decimal represented in normal order, there could be a representation that does reverse order

Comment: Thank you, that was the sort of confirmation or refutation I was looking for.